# Why Error CameraUpdateFactory not initialized in MapsFragment android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to display some point in the map , but when I set the camera on a map why this error occurs ? If this goes wrong with the order CameraUpdateFactory program , previously I did not experience an error

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bongkorr/com.hospifinder.Maps}: java.lang.NullPointerException: CameraUpdateFactory is not initialized`

Full is The draft code  of CameraUpdateFactory , is there something wrong with this ?

### Maps.java

```
public class Maps<Passing> extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private DBAdapter dbhelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dbhelper = new DBAdapter(this);
        db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        dbhelper.delAllData(db);
        //dbhelper.delAllData2(db);
        dbhelper.generateDataLokasi(db);
        dbhelper.generateDataRS(db);
        setContentView(R.layout.maps);



        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = fm.getMap();

        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-6.604345,
                106.796640), 12));

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Cursor c = dbhelper.fetchAllLokasi(db);
        int col = dbhelper.fetchAllLokasi(db).getCount();




        if (col == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(Maps.this, "Pas de donnees ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        } else {

            c.moveToFirst();
            while (c.isAfterLast() == false) {

    String id = "" + c.getInt(0);
    String nama = c.getString(1);
    String longitude = c.getString(3);
    String latitude = c.getString(2);
    String ket = c.getString(4);


    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(
            new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude), Double
                    .parseDouble(longitude)))
    .title(nama)
    .snippet(ket)

    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.icmarker)));
c.moveToNext();



            }
        }
```

I have not found on this answer , several times I run this application , fixed the error , if there is something wrong with my code ? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to explicit call to  `MapsInitializer`.

Sample code:

```
@Override public View 
onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_panel, container, false);
    mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    configureMap(mapView.getMap());
    return view;
}

private void 
configureMap(GoogleMap map, double lat, double lon)
{
    if (map == null)
        return; // Google Maps not available
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    }
    catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Have GoogleMap but then error", e);
        return;
    }
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
    CameraUpdate camera = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng);
    map.animateCamera(camera);
}
```